# Chocolatey Package Failing

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-prompt, chocolatey

When trying to create a Chocolatey package for ARM RVDS 4.1, it fails and I am not sure what the issue is. I believe I either set up the `chocolateyinstall.ps1` incorrectly or something with the `setup.exe` being in the tools folder.

Here is the error I get in the cmd: https://ibb.co/KmDPxcF

Here is the `chocolateyinstall.ps1`: https://ibb.co/yR7ysqR

Here is the `.nuspec`: https://ibb.co/hBM3xn9

Here is a look inside the `tools` folder: https://ibb.co/8NGXPNW

Can I not use the environment variable as the file location in the `chocolateyinstall.ps1`? Or is it a different problem? 
I also have suspicion that I might be using the wrong `silentArg`.

Edit: I have found some info on why the error says `access is denied`, but it all relates to an antivirus, which I don't have.

Comment: A quick look shows one of the errors is just "access is denied" - are you running as admin?

Comment: show more you code, error tell that problem in some invoke method called Start, show this fragment of your code.And show log file chocolatey.

Comment: @Matthew @Vad I was running as an admin and this is all the code I have besides the batch script that actually tries to install the package. But all the batch file has is just: `choco install armrvds -r -y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation here:

https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-install-package#file-string

> Full file path to native installer to run. If embedding in the package,
>   you can get it to the path with
>   "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)\INSTALLER_FILE"
>
> In 0.10.1+, FileFullPath is an alias for File.
>
> This can be a 32-bit or 64-bit file. This is mandatory in earlier versions
>   of Chocolatey, but optional if File64 has been provided.

You are currently passing a directory to the file parameter, which is incorrect.

Comment: After changing the `chocolateyinstall.ps1` to have `File: $(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)\setup.exe`, it gives me an error saying "Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified".